# mat-card, how to change default padding

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to change the global, default padding on a Angular Material, mat-card.

In the angular.json I have this specification:

```
 "styles": [
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",           
          "src/styles/app.theme.scss",
          "src/styles/styles.scss"
        ],
```

i make the adjustment inside of styles.scss

```
.mat-card {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;}
```

Result is that margin works, while padding does not. this is the result in the devtools. I see there is a .mat-card in `<style>` that takes precedence.

How do I set the padding on a global basis on a `mat-card`?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You must scope them. Angular will take css of its own component first. So if you want to change globally scope them with any class name such as 'custom'.

```
<mat-card class="custom"></mat-card>
```

In stylesheet

```
.custom.mat-card{
  //your styles
 }
```

To know more, refer to [angular material customizing](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles#styling-overlay-components)

Comment: While this is a good approach, and one I advocate - you can actually globally override the material classes in the global scope (`styles.scss` or other configured style files in `angular.json`). You just have to be careful with how specific your selectors are. This is the same for any component with `encapsulation` set to `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

Comment: Yes. Need to be careful while setting ViewEncapsulation.None

Comment: This works! However if I follow BEM naming methodology and use <mat-card class="mat-card mat-card--custom"...> It doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 3):

dotless: .mat-card --> mat-card

```css
mat-card { margin: 5px; padding: 5px;}
```